# How to do customer segmentation based on their orders in different years using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to make customer segments based on their orders in different years (number of days before last order) using a SQL query. Below are the segments that I want:

- New Customer = Made an order for the very first time in whole data
- Repeat Customer L1 = Made an order at least once in last one year (365days)
- Repeat Customer L2 = Made an order at least once in last two years (but not in last one year)
- Repeat Customer L3 = Made an order at least once in last three years (but not in last two years)
- Unspecified = Any order that does not have any of the above conditions

This is the table that I have: (Small example, the data that I have is too huge)

| Date(yyyymmdd) | Customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 20180403 | abc123 |
| 20180711 | def456 |
| 20180625 | mno789 |
| 20181123 | abc123 |
| 20190130 | ghi123 |
| 20190321 | def456 |
| 20190909 | ghi123 |
| 20191225 | jkl456 |
| 20200205 | abc123 |
| 20200617 | ghi123 |
| 20200817 | hij123 |
| 20210307 | mno789 |
| 20211009 | xyz345 |

This is the output I am trying to get through SQL (I am new to SQL):

| Year | Customer_id | Segment | Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | abc123 | New Customer | 2 |
| 2018 | def456 | New Customer | 1 |
| 2018 | mno789 | New Customer | 1 |
| 2019 | ghi123 | New Customer | 2 |
| 2019 | def456 | Repeat Customer L1 | 1 |
| 2019 | jkl456 | New Customer | 1 |
| 2020 | abc123 | Repeat Customer L2 | 1 |
| 2020 | ghi123 | Repeat Customer L1 | 1 |
| 2020 | hij123 | New Customer | 1 |
| 2021 | mno789 | Repeat Customer L3 | 1 |
| 2021 | xyz345 | New Customer | 1 |

Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With the data that you shared being:

```
WITH input as(
SELECT '20180403' as DATE,  'abc123' as Customer_Id UNION ALL
SELECT '20180711',  'def456'UNION ALL
SELECT '20180625',  'mno789'UNION ALL
SELECT '20181123',  'abc123'UNION ALL
SELECT '20190130',  'ghi123'UNION ALL
SELECT '20190321',  'def456'UNION ALL
SELECT '20190909',  'ghi123'UNION ALL
SELECT '20191225',  'jkl456'UNION ALL
SELECT '20200205',  'abc123'UNION ALL
SELECT '20200617',  'ghi123'UNION ALL
SELECT '20200817',  'hij123'UNION ALL
SELECT '20210307',  'mno789'UNION ALL
SELECT '20211009',  'xyz345'
)
```

I used 3 `common_table_expresion`, I used `row_number` to bring the `transaction_column` that has the same `Year` and the same `customer_Id` and I use a `CASE` expression to bring the Segment column according to the values that you shared that depends on the year column.

```
with YearExtr as (
 SELECT SUBSTR(DATE, 1,4) as Year,input.Customer_Id FROM input
), transactcOL as(
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y",PARSE_DATE("%Y", Year))as Real_Year, Customer_Id, MAX(transaction_col) as transaction_col,Cast(FORMAT_DATE("%Y",PARSE_DATE("%Y", Year))as INT)as Formated_Year FROM
(SELECT * ,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YearExtr.Year, YearExtr.Customer_Id
                   ORDER BY YearExtr.Year DESC) as transaction_col
  from YearExtr
order by YearExtr.Year  )
GROUP BY Year, Customer_Id
), lastexp as(
SELECT DISTINCT tcol.Real_Year, tcol.Customer_Id,
CASE
WHEN tcol.Formated_Year>=t2.Formated_Year AND ((tcol.Formated_Year)-(t2.Formated_Year))=1 THEN 'Repeat Customer L1'
WHEN tcol.Formated_Year>=t2.Formated_Year AND ((tcol.Formated_Year)-(t2.Formated_Year))=2 THEN 'Repeat Customer L2'
WHEN tcol.Formated_Year>=t2.Formated_Year AND ((tcol.Formated_Year)-(t2.Formated_Year))=3 THEN 'Repeat Customer L3'
ELSE 'New Customer'
END as Segment, tcol.transaction_col,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tcol.Real_Year, tcol.Customer_Id
                   ORDER BY tcol.Formated_Year DESC) as rown
FROM transactcOL tcol left join transactcOL t2
USING (Customer_Id)
GROUP BY tcol.Real_Year, tcol.Customer_Id, tcol.Formated_Year, t2.Formated_Year, tcol.transaction_col
)
SELECT lastexp.Real_Year, lastexp.Customer_Id, lastexp.Segment, lastexp.transaction_col
FROM lastexp WHERE rown=1
```

The Output is:

[image: Output image]